# How to prepare for a serial interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

What's the best way to prepare for a job interview where you will meet with several different interviewers, about half an hour each, over a period of several hours?

Comment: As evidenced by [this closed question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13398/how-to-prepare-for-an-interview?rq=1) this is likely too open-ended and therefore off-topic. A better defined version of this question might be something along the lines of "How does a serial interview differ from a regular interview?"

Answer (score 3):

Beside the preparation you would take for any job interview, I would recommend the following things:

- Prepare Snacks (Interviews are exhausting and you will want to stay fit for the day)
- Water (Obviously like with the snacks, hydration is important)
- Sage-candy (If you are not used to speak all day long; alternative would be some drops of honey in water)
- Make sure you know time & place were you meet and make sure that interviews don't overlap. You don't want to let the interviewers wait (in case not all interviews happen in the same office)
- Get to know where the restrooms are (not kidding, otherwise the day will be more stressful)
- (Optionally) Watch (Does not need to recharge like your phone)

Other than that I don't think there is much to be prepare compared to normal interviews. If you know who is interviewing, then you could look up information about their department and related topics.

Not sure if that was the kind of answers you were hoping for, maybe it helps a little.

Comment: Non-messy snacks. Nothing that will shed on your interviewing garb.

Comment: Take notes and write down people's names, too.